# ant-design: bad type declarations?

Tags: typescript-typings, antd

There is this tutorial on the main page: https://ant.design/docs/react/use-in-typescript it shows some example code that does not compile. In particular, `<Button type="primary">Button</Button>` does not compile because it should be `htmlType` and not `type`. Can somebody please confirm that this is true? Or is it just a problem with my installation?

Another problem I have noticed is that props for `Button` have bad type declaration. At least on my computer. I just installed antd, and I have this `NativeButtonProps`, which has `htmlType?: ButtonHTMLType`, and that is declared as: `export declare type ButtonHTMLType = 'submit' | 'button' | 'reset';`
This is very confusing because the documentation says that there are types called "`primary`" "`dashed`" and "`danger`". Is this also a problem with the declaration?

Is it possible that I have a broken installation but I doubt. I have tried to install everything from scratch on a computer that had no node.js installed. But the result is the same. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE** more details on the problem. If I use this code:

```
<Button type="primary">Buttonka</Button>
```

Then I get this compilation error and it won't generate js code:

C:/TypeScript/antd-demo-ts/src/App.tsx
(10,10): Type '{ children: string; type: "primary"; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Pick & Readonly & Pick, "htmlType">, "color" | ... 258 more ... | "htmlType"> & Partial<...> & Partial<...>) | ...'.
  Type '{ children: string; type: "primary"; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick & Readonly & Pick, "htmlType">, "color" | ... 262 more ... | "value">'.
    Property 'htmlType' is missing in type '{ children: string; type: "primary"; }'.

If I use `htmlType="primary"` instead, then I get the following warning:

{
    "resource": "/c:/TypeScript/antd-demo-ts/src/App.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2322",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type '{ children: string; htmlType: \"primary\"; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & R...'.\n  Type '{ children: string; htmlType: \"primary\"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Re...'.\n    Type '{ children: string; htmlType: \"primary\"; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.\n      Types of property 'htmlType' are incompatible.\n        Type '\"primary\"' is not assignable to type '\"submit\" | \"button\" | \"reset\" | undefined'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 10,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 16
}

and in this case the TypeScript code is compiled, but the button is shown as opaque/white, and it is not primary/blue.

It is a fact that the css has been imported into App.tsx:

```
import './App.css';
```

and also the ant design css has been imported in App.css:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';
```

But either way, I can't set the primary (blue) style on the button.

Comment: Ant design Button has types like primary, dashed and danger... If you are using ant design button inside a form tag, you should use htmlType= "submit" to make the button work as normal submit button else it wont trigger the form action.

Comment: So if you would like to use inside a form, you can have both attributes htmlType and type, If it is just a button in your website for navigation then type attribute is sufficient to show some beautification for your button

Comment: I don't want to use it inside of a form. My problem is that using `htmlType="primary"` gives a compilation **warning** and it does not work (e.g. the button is not primary blue but opaque). Specifying `type="primary"` does not work either, because it gives a compilation **error**. I'm going to add more details to the question.

Comment: @nagylzs there's no such value for the prop `htmlType` as `primary`. `htmlType` prop can only be either `button`, `submit` or `reset`. If you can give more information about the error it shows when you use the `type="primary"` without a `htmlType` attribute, that'd be great cause that's the correct way of declaring it.